# io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Написал онлайн чат https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-websocket-chat-demo

И хочу переписать метод configureMessageBroker для доступа с другого сервера.

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic").setRelayHost("localhost").setRelayPort(3000);
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
```

Но возникает ошибка

io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand.HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561030/1911548

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я хочу отправлять запросы с другого сервера который запускаю на локалхосте с портом 3000, не думаю что тот ответ подходит здесь

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в классе WebSocketConfig в методе registerStompEndpoints(...) добавить строчку

```
registry.setAllowedOrigins("*");
```

Comment: но мне ведь надо отправлять сообщения на домен localhost:3000/**/topic , а без нужной конфигурации оно считает что домен topic относится к серверу с которого запускается а это localhost:8080

Comment: Опишите тогда, пожалуйста, что конкретно требуется сделать)

Comment: @Yuri Bulis мне нужно переписать строку с enableStompBrokerRelay, чтобы оно не выбивало ошибку, чтобы я указал ендпоинт для удаленного сервера